# print css selector matching all elements except one

Tags: html, css

I have a page with multiple divs. Inside this page, there is a div with a specific class printThis. So for example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="title">Hello</div>

    <div class="printThis">Help</div>
    <div class="printThis">Me</div>

    <div id="bottomPage">About me</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now in my @media print, I am using:

```
.printThis {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  @page {
    size: A4 potrait;
    margin: 0;
  }

  html,
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vw;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  body *:not(.printThis) {
    display: none;
  }

  body div.printThis {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

The `.printThis` class is set to `display: none` normally but in my printing css it is set to `display:block`. The problem is, when I print, I get a blank page. Is there a way to make this print and allow each div with the `printThis` class to print on its own page?

Many Thanks.

Comment: this works fine

Comment: Works perfectly when i debug it on my end as well. This is written exactly as it should be. These do however not print each line on its own page, but its a little unclear if thats what you expect it to do when you say `It is meant to print one per page as well``

Comment: Ok you are right. I was using edge when I got this error. But it works in chrome. However still a problem as it is supposed to print Help on one page, then me on the other. Thanks.

Comment: Ill add an answer to solve this for you. a page break is needed in your CSS class for printThis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code workes perfectly as written for print functinality however what your missing is a page break. change:

```
body div.printThis {
    display: block;
}
```

To:

```
body div.printThis {
    display: block;
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

This will make each `<div class="printThis">thing</div>` display on its own page.